# GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES TO user; in Postgres < 9

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-grant

PostgreSQL 9 brought the new GRANT Option "...ON ALL TABLES...".

How can I do the same in PostgreSQL 8.2?

I have a Database 'myDatabase'
In myDatabse are 2 Schemas 'public' and 'myschema' with each around 20 Tables.
Now I created a new user for testing which needs to have all privileges on 'myschema'.

I already tried:

```
GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA myschema TO testuser;
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE myDatabse TO testuser;
GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema; (Which doesn't work in postgres 8)
```

What would work is the following. But I'm sure there must be a better way:

```
GRANT ALL ON myschema.table1 TO testuser;
GRANT ALL ON myschema.table2 TO testuser;
...
GRANT ALL ON myschema.tableN TO testuser;
```

Comment: 8.2 is no longer supported and you should not use it. You really have to upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Would they have introduced the `ALL TABLES` way if there was already a "better way"?

Comment: I need to use 8.2 in my company. There's no way to upgrade it on my own.

Comment: Create a role and give it access to all tables.  Grant permission to the role every time you add a table.